# Move items of an array into the start of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an `array` that contains some other `arrays`, I will make a sample of the original structure below in order to understand my issue.

```
$foo = array(
[0] => array('name' => foo, 'offered' => 1)
[1] => array('name' => foo)
[2] => array('name' => foo, 'offered' => 1)
[3] => array('name' => foo, 'offered' => 1)
);
```

What i want to do is, to sort my array in order to get first every array that contains the key 'offered'. In the example above i need do get this type of order. [0],[2],[3],[1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `uasort()` with a custom comparison function.

```
$foo = array(
   array('name' => 'mark', 'offered' => 1),
   array('name' => 'joe'),
   array('name' => 'bill', 'offered' => 1),
   array('name' => 'hugo', 'offered' => 1)
);

uasort($foo, 'customSort');

function customSort($a, $b) {
    $a = isset($a['offered']);
    $b = isset($b['offered']);
    if (($a && $b) || (!$a && !$b)) return 0;
    else if ($a && !$b) return -1;
    else return 1; 
}

print_r($foo);
```

Please check:

http://php.net/manual/it/function.usort.php

http://php.net/manual/it/function.uasort.php

http://php.net/manual/it/function.uksort.php

**Explanation:** (a bit simplified for newcomers) When you sort an array with these special sorting functions, you can tell PHP to use a custom function to let it decide whether a value is "less than another" (and return 1) or "greater than" another (and return -1) or "equal to another" (and return 0).
This functions has as parameters (`$a`, `$b`) the two array items to compare.

In this case we decide that the ones where `"offered"` exists are "less than" the others, so they will be sorted first.

Comment: Nice answer Cranio! That did the trick. Can you also please explain to me the function you used cause i'm a little bit cofused?

Comment: @Makis I've edited the question with an explanation :)

Comment: Ok, now it is more clear to understand! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would iterate and check if the key exists, depending on that, rebuild the array.

```
$final = [];
foreach ($foo as $r) {
    if (isset($r['offered']))
        array_unshift($final, $r);
    else
        array_push($final, $r);
}
var_dump($final);
```

Comment: Good but not very efficient, as it iterates more times than necessary on all the array items.

Comment: I agree. `uasort` is the best option.

Comment: Yes, `uasort` uses an implementation of QuickSort, so it should be faster

Comment: @Cranio can you go into more details.. if I iterate through my loop, it iterates 4 times, however with `uasort`, it iterates 5 times. Can you explain why `uasort` still is the best option?

Comment: Why would uasort iterate 5 times? Quicksort has an efficiency of O(n log n), one of the best options. 
Besides, your code will iterate and compute the second array for every item even if they are already in a perfect order.

Comment: i say that because if you place an `echo` inside your `customSort` function, it echos 5 times. however, I do agree that O(n log n) is best. Just thought you would have a good explanation for this.

Answer (score 1):

I find the spaceship operator (php7+) to provide a very clean syntax.

Evaluate the `offered` column from both `$a` and `$b` to check if the column is set.  If not the `isset()` `false` will be treated as `0`, otherwise `true` will be treated as `1`.

By writing `$b` on the left of the operator and `$a` on the right, DESC sorting is performed -- this positions all `1` (`true`) evaluations before `0` (`false`) evaluations.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uKLvo))

```
$array = [
    ['name' => 'a', 'offered' => 1],
    ['name' => 'b'],
    ['name' => 'c', 'offered' => 1],
    ['name' => 'd', 'offered' => 1],
    ['name' => 'e']
];

usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return isset($b['offered']) <=> isset($a['offered']);
});

var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'a',
    'offered' => 1,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'c',
    'offered' => 1,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'd',
    'offered' => 1,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'b',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'e',
  ),
)
```